# 404 Page Translations : German, French

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I'm looking for a German translation of the stock Magento 1.9 404 page.

It's so hard to find one online, only standard DE translation locale pages are available.

But definitely need this too!

The stock looks like this :

======================================================

Whoops, our bad...

The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

```
    If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
    If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
```

What can you do?
    Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on track.

```
    Go back to the previous page.
    Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products.
    Follow these links to get you back on track!
    Store Home | My Account
```

Comment: I think the most installed german language pack is https://github.com/riconeitzel/German_LocalePack_de_DE. This however is not the stock language pack. If there exists one (I am not sure), you can find it probably in https://github.com/firegento/magento/releases

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is wondering.

I went to this website which listed German websites using Magento (https://trends.builtwith.com/shop/Magento/Germany) and saw how other people have done it there.